# How to make scrollbar to see full content in below case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

see demo url of the framework i'm using: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationH.html#secondPage

However,using almost same kind of code from above, 
when I try to achieve below effect in which title text is excluded from slider. (title text to be static, and content is sliding)

```
jsfiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/097wvnot/8/
```

I can't scroll to see all the content; what's the best code to achieve this effect?

if i want to use the top framework, must i do a lot of hack into its core functions?
if not hacking the top animation framework , what are other recommendations to this effect

Comment: What browser are you using? And when you say scroll, do you mean that you page left and right? I seem to be able to see all the slides 1-4. When I have my mouse over the center div with the scroll bar on slide  1 and 2 I am able to use my scroll wheel to scroll down and see the rest of the content on slide 1 and 2 respectively. I am using Chrome.

Comment: Hi, @Jazzepi, i think it is independent with browsers, but depends on the device height as the plugin dynamically calculate the section height, if u use high res with huge device height to view it there might be no scrollbar and all content can be seen, but as long as you resize window in lower height, the overflow part can not be view by scrolling (as it's out of the scroll section).

Comment: In first slide i've written line1 to line30, however when you resize the device height to lower browser height values, you can only see some but not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `absolute` positioned element for your title. Fullpage.js calculates the height of your content inside the `slide` elements. (as they are suppose to be full height...).
If you place anything outside any slide, it would have to be absoluted positioned.

Take a look at the solution I propose: http://jsfiddle.net/097wvnot/11/

I added the following style to your title:

```
#demo{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    margin: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugin is calculating the height of the fp-scrollable incorrectly. At least for your use case. I was able to get it looking good by just manually adjusting the fp-scrollable's height attribute to a smaller amount (obviously that is not a long term fix, just something I was doing for testing). I'm not sure if the calculating takes into account your font size, and things like that, so that might effect it.

If you want to hack on the plugin, generally the place you need to make your changes is fairly restricted, and wouldn't be too bad. From the github page. https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.js

All you need to do is fix the value being placed into the scrollHeight variable. I'm not sure exactly what it's not accounting for in the scroll height calculation (the scrollHeight needs to be smaller in your case, it's too big), but I think that's an exercise you can try your hand at first :) I've got to get to bed z.z

You also may need to mess with the calculation for the contentHeight, since ostensibly you'll be shrinking the scrollHeight, and the script only puts the scroll bar on there if the content is bigger than the scroll.

```
    function createSlimScrolling(element){
        //needed to make `scrollHeight` work under Opera 12
        element.css('overflow', 'hidden');

        //in case element is a slide
        var section = element.closest('.fp-section');
        var scrollable = element.find('.fp-scrollable');

        //if there was scroll, the contentHeight will be the one in the scrollable section
        if(scrollable.length){
            var contentHeight = scrollable.get(0).scrollHeight;
        }else{
            var contentHeight = element.get(0).scrollHeight;
            if(options.verticalCentered){
                contentHeight = element.find('.fp-tableCell').get(0).scrollHeight;
            }
        }

        var scrollHeight = windowsHeight - parseInt(section.css('padding-bottom')) - parseInt(section.css('padding-top'));

        //needs scroll?
        if ( contentHeight > scrollHeight) {
            //was there already an scroll ? Updating it
            if(scrollable.length){
                scrollable.css('height', scrollHeight + 'px').parent().css('height', scrollHeight + 'px');
            }
            //creating the scrolling
            else{
                if(options.verticalCentered){
                    element.find('.fp-tableCell').wrapInner('<div class="fp-scrollable" />');
                }else{
                    element.wrapInner('<div class="fp-scrollable" />');
                }

                element.find('.fp-scrollable').slimScroll({
                    allowPageScroll: true,
                    height: scrollHeight + 'px',
                    size: '10px',
                    alwaysVisible: true
                });
            }
        }

        //removing the scrolling when it is not necessary anymore
        else{
            removeSlimScroll(element);
        }

        //undo
        element.css('overflow', '');
    }
```

Comment: I noticed this but why i am very caucious of hacking plugin core is that as long as i use "scrollOverflow: true" option, not only the  slider part, every scroll section part might also fire createSlimScrolling function. And that is bit confusing for me to make hacking decision.   Thanks anyway and have a good rest.